# Sequelize dirty model

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way in `sequelize` to be able to check if a model has been changed?  For example

```
var user = User.findOne(where:{email:'test@user.com'}).then(user=>{
   if(some_condition)user.email = 'changed@email.com'
   //can I do something like this to check if model has been changed? before the save action?
   if(user.dirty){}
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize does have a changed method at the model instance level, But this compares the current values with `_previousDataValues`.

Its been documented [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-changed)

It could be used as

```
Model.testModel.findById(23)
.then(instance => {
   instance.name = "new Name";
   console.log(instance.changed());
   // This should log [name] and would be false if nothing was changed.
})
```